# Remote XML Query of Large File in .NET without Downloading

Tags: .net, xml

Is there a way to query a large remote xml file in .net where the whole file does not have to be downloaded or loaded on every query?

For example can the xml be queried remotely with some parameters and only a select set of data is returned or does the whole file have to be loaded then parsed through?

Comment: Of course; have the remote machine with the XML file accept the query and return just the results. This is pretty much the way all web sites work; did you have some special restrictions you haven't told us about?

Comment: Since .NET processes the query .NET needs to access the XML directly.  The solution is for .NET to process on the remote machine.  WCF is designed for that.  http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd456779.aspx